# Android Studio using http version of mavenCentral

Tags: maven, android-studio, gradle

I just updated from Android Studio 4.1.1 to 4.2.2. Below is my project build.gradle file. Since updating, running my app works fine, but running tests fail. Machines with Android Studio 4.1.1 running the tests still work.

I understand that request to the maven repo now require https, but I don't have the reference in by gradle file. It's acting as though 4.2.2 changed the mavenCentral repo to use http instead of https, otherwise, I'm unsure why this worked in 4.1.1 but not 4.2.2. Is there a way to force the repo to be https?

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.3.72'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            // Needs to be here to be included in both misnap and app modules
            dirs project(':misnapworkflow_UX2').file('libs')
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = '29.0.2'
    compileSdkVersion = 29
    minSdkVersion = 21
    targetSdkVersion = 29

    daggerVersion = '2.27'
    okHttpVersion = '4.7.2'
}
```

Error when running tests

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers$6 (file:/Users/jwhitsit/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.robolectric/shadowapi/4.3.1/a93e55b36c418aa3afc17c26eac82590a3bfb63e/shadowapi-4.3.1.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.getPackage(java.lang.String)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers$6
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[Robolectric] com.commercebank.honeybadger.chat.ChatWindowFragmentTest.whenMinimizeClicked_CloseFragment: sdk=28; resources=BINARY
Downloading from maven 
Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/10-robolectric-5803371/android-all-10-robolectric-5803371.pom from repository sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
Error transferring file: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:pom:10-robolectric-5803371' from repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/): Error transferring file: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/10-robolectric-5803371/android-all-10-robolectric-5803371.pom from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 501 for URL: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/robolectric/android-all/10-robolectric-5803371/android-all-10-robolectric-5803371.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:pom:10-robolectric-5803371' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 501 for URL: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/robolectric/android-all/10-robolectric-5803371/android-all-10-robolectric-5803371.pom
Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/10-robolectric-5803371/android-all-10-robolectric-5803371.jar from repository sonatype at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/
Error transferring file: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:jar:10-robolectric-5803371' from repository sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/): Error transferring file: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/10-robolectric-5803371/android-all-10-robolectric-5803371.jar from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 501 for URL: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/robolectric/android-all/10-robolectric-5803371/android-all-10-robolectric-5803371.jar
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:jar:10-robolectric-5803371' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 501 for URL: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/robolectric/android-all/10-robolectric-5803371/android-all-10-robolectric-5803371.jar

Unable to resolve artifact: Missing:
----------
1) org.robolectric:android-all:jar:10-robolectric-5803371

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.robolectric -DartifactId=android-all -Dversion=10-robolectric-5803371 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.robolectric -DartifactId=android-all -Dversion=10-robolectric-5803371 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0
    2) org.robolectric:android-all:jar:10-robolectric-5803371

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/)



    at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.DependenciesTask.doExecuteResolution(DependenciesTask.java:268)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.DependenciesTask.doExecute(DependenciesTask.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.AbstractArtifactTask.execute(AbstractArtifactTask.java:751)
    at org.robolectric.internal.dependency.MavenDependencyResolver.whileLocked(MavenDependencyResolver.java:95)
    at org.robolectric.internal.dependency.MavenDependencyResolver.getLocalArtifactUrls(MavenDependencyResolver.java:74)
    at org.robolectric.internal.dependency.MavenDependencyResolver.getLocalArtifactUrls(MavenDependencyResolver.java:39)
    at org.robolectric.internal.dependency.MavenDependencyResolver.getLocalArtifactUrl(MavenDependencyResolver.java:107)
    at org.robolectric.internal.dependency.CachedDependencyResolver.getLocalArtifactUrl(CachedDependencyResolver.java:44)
    at org.robolectric.plugins.CachedMavenDependencyResolver.getLocalArtifactUrl(CachedMavenDependencyResolver.java:32)
    at org.robolectric.plugins.LegacyDependencyResolver.getLocalArtifactUrl(LegacyDependencyResolver.java:86)
    at org.robolectric.plugins.DefaultSdkProvider$DefaultSdk.getJarPath(DefaultSdkProvider.java:127)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.loadAppPackage_measured(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:309)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.lambda$loadAppPackage$1(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:284)
    at org.robolectric.util.PerfStatsCollector.measure(PerfStatsCollector.java:53)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.loadAppPackage(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:282)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.installAndCreateApplication(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:178)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.setUpApplicationState(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:169)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.beforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:301)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:243)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.MultipleArtifactsNotFoundException: Missing:
----------
1) org.robolectric:android-all:jar:10-robolectric-5803371

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.robolectric -DartifactId=android-all -Dversion=10-robolectric-5803371 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.robolectric -DartifactId=android-all -Dversion=10-robolectric-5803371 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0
    2) org.robolectric:android-all:jar:10-robolectric-5803371

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/)


    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:360)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.DependenciesTask.doExecuteResolution(DependenciesTask.java:263)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to upgrade your Android Gradle build plugin to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
```

Alternatively, as a workaround, you could try to replace `mavenCentral()` with

```
maven { url "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Faced with the same issue on Windows. removing the following folder:

- On Windows: *%USERPROFILE%\.m2\repository\org\robolectric*
- On Mac / UNIX: *~/.m2/repository/org/robolectric*

resolved the issue for me.